# How to create sequence using starting value from query?

Tags: sql, postgresql, psql

In database migration script (psql) I want to create sequence starting from certain value queried from table, like:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE book_id_seq START ( SELECT MAX(id) + 1 FROM book.book );
```

or tried to set `\set start (SELECT MAX(id) + 1 FROM book.book)` to use variable like:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE book_id_seq START :'start';
```

But using `\set` did not inerpret the query.

Another way setting variable did not work also

```
start := SELECT MAX(id) + 1 FROM book.book;
```

gave error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near ":="
LINE 1: start := SELECT MAX(id) + 1 FROM book.book;
```

Selecting value INTO does not help also, because accessing needs another SELECT query.

Using static value works fine:

```
\set start 33
CREATE SEQUENCE book_id_seq START :'start'::int;
```

How to use dynamic starting value?

Postgres 9.6

Comment: Why do you want to use a sequence?  Just define a serial value.

Comment: @GordonLinoff it is relevant to my other Q/A https://stackoverflow.com/a/50388597/196241, need to handle separate sequences for one table, to summarize problem in short.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you can use [`setval()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-sequence.html) after you created the sequence:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE book_id_seq;
select setval('book_id_seq', (SELECT MAX(id) + 1 FROM book.book));
```

Comment: Nice approach, still keen to understand, how to assign dynamic value in script.